# Nested states with angular-ui-router redirected to the parent state

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create Nested States with `ui-routes` on AngularJS:

```
.state('compare', {
    url: '/compare',
    templateUrl: '/views/compare.list.html',
    controller: 'CompareListCtrl'
})

.state('compare.compare', {
    url: '/compare',
    templateUrl: '/views/compare.table.html',
    controller: 'CompareTableCtrl'
})

.state('compare.compareTwo', {
    url: '/:models',
    templateUrl: '/views/compareTwo.html',
    controller: 'CompareTwoCtrl'
})
```

If I go to `compare/compare` or `compare/thinkpad-t400-and-thinkpad-x200`, url stays the same but  `"compare"` state view and controller shows.

**Why is that and how can I fix that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created [working plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1qTZymf85YspB5TLD5Wf?p=preview). I would guess, that you forgot to provide a target for child states.

This should be the parent view

```
<div>
    <h1>compare</h1>

    with a target for child here:

    <hr />

    <div ui-view=""></div>
</div>
```

Check that there is anchor/target **`<div ui-view="">`**. This way, each child will be injected into parent's unnamed view.

*With the almost the same (plunker adjusted) states it is working:*

```
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/compare');

  // States
  $stateProvider
    .state('compare', {
      url: '/compare',
      templateUrl: 'views/compare.list.html',
      controller: 'CompareListCtrl'
    })

  .state('compare.compare', {
    url: '/compare',
    templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
    controller: 'CompareTableCtrl'
  })

  .state('compare.compareTwo', {
    url: '/:models',
    templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
    controller: 'CompareTwoCtrl'
  });
```

Check it [in action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1qTZymf85YspB5TLD5Wf?p=preview)